# How to describe the predicate/edge of a triple in JSON-LD?

Tags: json-ld

I am new to JSON-LD and LOD so please excuse my use of terminology. I am working on creating a data model in JSON-LD to describe aggregated digital collections based on the European Data Model (http://pro.europeana.eu/edm-documentation).

I would like to create an @context area that describes the relationship:

ore:Aggregation  --- edm:aggregatedCHO -->  edm:ProvidedCHO

(where 'edm:aggregatedCHO' is the predicate/edge), but I would like to label edm:ProvidedCHO as 'sourceResource' in my model.

Currently my @context looks something like this:

```
{
    "@context": {

        "edm" : "http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/",

        "sourceResource" : {
            "@id" : "edm:ProvidedCHO",
            "@type" : "edm:aggregatedCHO" 

        }
    }
}
```

My intention was to define the predicate ('edge') using @type, and the node contents using @id, but after reviewing the W3C Recommendation, this seems incorrect, and that 'edm:ProvidedCHO' should actually be the @type, because it describes the content type of the node (http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#typed-values).

My question, generally, is where/how do you include the predicate of a triple in a JSON-LD @context statement?

In this case specifically, how do I represent a node called 'sourceResource' that contains edm:ProvidedCHO objects that are each an edm:aggregatedCHO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that setting @type in the context says that the term is expected to be a literal with that datatype; you probably want to use this @type in the body, which will create a *type edge*, if you will.

Note that the @context does not define relationships, but terms, and how the values of the terms should be interpreted (along with a couple of other things). I think what you want is to have an @context that simply defines terms you want to use in the body of the JSON, where you can define your nodes and they're relationships.

This *might* be something like the following:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "edm" : "http://www.europeana.eu/schemas/edm/",
    "ore": "http://example/",
    "edm:aggregatedCHO": {"@type": "@id"}
  },
  "@id": "ore:Aggregation",
  "edm:aggregatedCHO": "edm:ProvidedCHO"
}
```

It's always good to test your JSON-LD on the JSON-LD playground, or some similar service or tool.

Comment: Your clarification between the use of @type in the @context area and body is very helpful - I think I was trying to do too much in the @context area.  However, I would still like to use the alias `sourceResource` for my `ProvidedCHO` to add clarity and reduce clutter in my JSON body. Is my use of the @type in this example an appropriate way to accomplish this?  http://pastie.org/9105617